# Algorithm for finding edge vertex points on a tilemap

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, tilemap, tiles

I have a 2d tilemap array contains 1 or 0. 0 corresponds empty tile, 1 corresponds solid tile. If tile is 1 I draw a texture.

I have to find edge vertices and coordinates that 1's grouped.

I couldn't find a way to implement this algorithm. Is there a algorithm or approach I could use?

Red dots are the vertices I want their coordinates.
[image: Tilemap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with implementing using [wall following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) algorithm. First find a starting point which is 0 in tilemap and it has to have only one adjacent tile as 1. After finding starting point I implemented a direction system. In my case it is following left hand wall(1 in tilemap). But whenever you turn left the front tile changes. This is the tricky point.